# MySQL & PHP leaderboard query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of players and I want to select the top 5 scores from the tables and print out the username and scores in descending order, what's the SQL statement for that?
and How to output the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5`

Explanations:

`SELECT * FROM yourtable`: we select `yourtable`.

`ORDER BY score DESC`: We order the results based on the column `score` and in descending order.

`LIMIT 5`: we limit the number of results by 5.

Comment: How to output the result such as    username     score?

Comment: What library/method are you using to connect to your MySQL database and what is your table structure?

Comment: id====username==score===address     4 columns,  I only need to print out the top 5 scores with username and score columns.

Comment: Well then, you need to connect to your database with PHP and if you run the SQL command I have given you it should give you what you want.

Comment: I got error  $query="SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 5";  $result=mysql_query($query);
             
               echo "<br>";
              echo "-----result of leaderboard is----------"  .$result;          ----result of leaderboard is----------Resource id #8

Comment: You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, I suggest that you read this page: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php